# Compiler for the B language

Tags: linux, compiler

It was mentioned that I can find a working [B compiler](https://github.com/Leushenko/ybc). Is that still my best alternative for a B compiler with Linux?

Comment: [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's owl is another man's nightingale.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Comment: What compiler have you tried already, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yasha's B Compiler](https://github.com/Leushenko/ybc) is a MIT-licensed B compiler for the x86 architecture (32-bit only). While it is written in BlitzMax (which may be problematic to compile), binaries are provided for Linux, Windows and Mac. It's quite likely that you won't be able to compile old B programs due to architectural differences (see the project's README for details), you can get the feel of B and write new programs if you're crazy enough.